# emberSync.find works, but emberSync.save() doesn't. Why?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase, emberfire, localforage

I am using ember-sync, ember-localforage-adapter and emberfire to solve offline storage in iOS/android apps problem. And for some unknown reason (I don't get any errors, that's the worst part) emberSync.find/pulling data from firebase works, but emberSync.save()/pushing data to firebase does not.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have raised an issue here: https://github.com/kurko/ember-sync/issues/22

If after loading application I do this in the console:

```
var route = Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES_BY_ID[''].__container__.lookup('route:index');
```

I get:

```
Class {routeName: "index", _names: Array[0], context: Class, currentModel: Class, controller: Class…}
```

then, when I type this:

```
var user = route.emberSync.createRecord('user', {name:'kurko'})
```

I get this:

```
Class {id: "8tp85", store: Class, container: Container, _changesToSync: Object, _deferredTriggers: Array[0]…}
```

and then when I type this:

```
user.emberSync.save()
```

I get this:

```
Class {__ember1412872464239: null, __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object, constructor: function, _super: function…}
```

`controllers/index.js`

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        save: function () {
        var user = this.emberSync.createRecord('user', { name: this.get('name') });
        user.emberSync.save();
        console.log(this.get('name'));
        console.log(user);
       } 
   }
});
```

`models/user.js`

```
var attr = DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string')
});
```

`routes/index.js`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
      return this.emberSync.find('user', '2oj9m');
      // return this.emberSync.createRecord('user', {name: 'Robinson'});
      console.log(this.emberSync.find('user', '5keks'));
    }
});
```

`templates/index.hbs`

```
{{input value=name}}
<button {{action "save"}}>Save</button>
```

Then I go to my firebase dashboard and I see that nothing has been added...

However, this: `route.emberSync.find('user', '2oj9m')` works fine and returns a promise

And all the code is available here (master branch): https://github.com/codepreneur/embersync-localforage-example